# 初期設定値とその変更値を保存しておくには？

Tags: ios8, xcode7

iOS8以降で、ソフトの初期値を保存しておくにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？

初期値の変更も保存したいのですが・・・

よろしくお願いします。

swift

```
// 「ud」というインスタンスをつくる。
let ud = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

// キーがidの値をとります。
var udId : AnyObject! = ud.objectForKey("id")

// これで表示してみたり。
print(udId)

// キーidに「taro」という値を格納。（idは任意の文字列でok）
ud.setObject("taro", forKey: "id")

// キーidの値を削除
ud.removeObjectForKey("id")
```

サンプル

```
 import UIKit

 class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func display() {
        let ud = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        var udId : AnyObject! = ud.objectForKey("id")
        println(udId)
    }

    @IBAction func put() {
        let ud2 = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        ud2.setObject("taro", forKey: "id")
    }

    @IBAction func delete() {
        let ud3 = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        ud3.removeObjectForKey("id")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults`クラスを使います。これはiOSのバージョンに関係ありません。iOS8以前と以降で、変化することはありません。

[NSUserDefaults Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/)

Comment: ありがとうございます。
初期値の設定はわかりました。

しかし初期値の変更はどうやって保存するのですか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「初期値の設定」と「初期値の変更」は、同じ処理ですよ。`set〜`メソッドで上書きするだけ。

Comment: なるほど。ありがとうございます。試してみます。